# Fix commit tree to make fast forward default again

Tags: git

I used to have my `dev` and `master` branches merged in fast forward mode, without asking me to name the commit. One time, I merged something directly to `master` and since then, it keeps asking me to name the commit for the merge, making additional commit called `Merge 'dev'`:

```
Merge branch 'dev'

# Please enter a commit message to explain why this merge is necessary,
# especially if it merges an updated upstream into a topic branch.
#
# Lines starting with '#' will be ignored, and an empty message aborts
# the commit.
```

Can I somehow *fix* my tree to merge in fast forward mode again?

Comment: Just rebase your *dev* branch against *master*. For example, *git pull —rebase origin master* when at *dev* branch.

Comment: I did `git rebase master`, without pulling, because my local master is the same as the remote one. It created 10 commits to push. I hope nothing breaks :)

Comment: Have you tried `git merge <branch.name> --ff-only` ?

Comment: Try @fabfas's suggestion, if that fails it means a fast forward merge isn't possible which is why it's doing it
Also check your git config, the `merge.ff` option controls the default behaviour with `false` equating to `--no-ff`.